# Increase precision of Python's time.process_time()

Tags: python

I want to increase the precision of Python's `process_time()` function.

Running the following code, I often get `elapsed_time` equal to 0, which is not satisfactory.

What could I do to improve precision?

```
t = time.process_time()
matches = search_kmp(x, p)
elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t
```

The purpose of the time measurements are benchmarking of algorithms.

Comment: What is the purpose of the time measurements? Benchmarking? Performance improvements?

Comment: how about execute search_kmp n times, and get the average time.

Comment: I could not reproduce this (using `10 in range(10)` instead of `matches = search_kmp(x, p)`). The printing of `elapsed_time` is always some number different from 0, in the range of 10^-5.

Comment: The purpose is benchmarking.

Comment: Did any of the answers provide a solution?

Comment: Thanks- why are your approach better than process_time()?

Comment: timeit is not better in general, just better suited to measure the execution time of small code. Sometimes the code is too fast to be measured accurately, each execution time might be slightly different, sometimes you have some overheard of creating variables, etc. timeit takes care of all those things by running the code several times, averaging, importing global variables, minimizing overhead, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to improve precision is to measure multiple times and average the results. Some functions are too fast to be measured accurately. Try using `timeit`, https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("search_kmp(x, p)", setup="from __main__ import search_kmp, x, p"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To benchmark small bits of Python code, use the `timeit` module. It lets you specify how many iterations to run, compensates for overhead, and has a CLI and programmatic interface.

An example:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
0.8187260627746582
>>> timeit.timeit('"-".join([str(n) for n in range(100)])', number=10000)
0.7288308143615723
>>> timeit.timeit('"-".join(map(str, range(100)))', number=10000)
0.5858950614929199
```